# Properties of Cantor set

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

$[0,1]$ is not homeomorphic to $[0,1]×[0,1]$ but $C$ is homeomorphic to $C \times C$ where $C$ is the Cantor set.

I know both the proof. I am asking which property of $C$ is the reason of this absurdity!

Comment: If you know both proofs, you know the reason: the Cantor set is totally disconnected, hence it is not really surprising that $K\times K$ is homeomorphic to $K$, especially if you think to the elements of $K$ as infinite strings over a ternary alphabet. On the other hand if we remove a point from $[0,1]$ we disconnect it, while $[0,1]\times[0,1]\setminus\{(a,b)\}$ still is connected.

Comment: Is it true that if $K \subset \mathbb{R} $ is totally disconnected then $K$ is homeomorphic to $K×K$?

Comment: I hope that is not true for finite set

Comment: No, it's not true for all totally disconnected subsets, e.g. $K=\{0\} \cup \{\frac1n: n \ge 1\}$ is an exception.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio the rationals certainly *is* homeomorphic to its square! Even any finite power.

Comment: @SantanuDebnath yes, if it's a subset of the reals. Then such a $K$ is just a Cantor set.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma: my bad, you're right.

Comment: It's not so strange for a topological space $S$ to be homeomorphic to $S\times S$. If $X$ is any space, let $S$ be the Tychonoff product of an infinity of copies of $X$. How big or small an infinity doesn't matter. In particular, with the discrete topology on $X=\{0,2\},$ the Cantor set is homeomorphic to the product of a countable infinity of copies of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$C$ is the (up to homeomorphism) unique zero-dimensional (or totally disconnected) compact metric space without isolated points.

If $X$ is such a space, so is $X^n$ for any $n$: still compact, totally disconnected, metric and no isolated points so it's homeomorphic to $X$.

Other spaces with unique charaterisations also have such preservations by finite products:

- $\mathbb{Q}$: the unique countable metric space without isolated points.
- $\mathbb{P}$ (the irrationals in the reals): the unique completely metrisable zero-dimensional separable metric space that is nowhere locally compact (i.e. the interior of any compact subset is empty).
- $C\setminus \{0\}$ (the Cantor set minus a point), the unique locally compact non-compact separable metric space that is totally disconnected.

And some more exist too. All of the above are homeomorphic to their squares.